# Convert Inner Join to Subquery in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, inner-join

I am joining two tables with the **student table** using the inner join below:

```
select (first_name || ' ' ||last_name) as "Student Name", gender, race from student
inner join gender on student.gender_id = gender.gender_id 
inner join race on student.race_id = race.race_id
```

I want to know how I can get the same result ***using a subquery*** instead of using inner join on PostgreSQL?

Below are my code for the three tables (Student, Gender, Race) that I have created:

```
create table Student(Student_ID int primary key, first_name varchar(30), last_name varchar(30), gender_id int, race_id int, constraint gender_id_fk foreign key(gender_id) references gender(gender_id), constraint race_id_fk foreign key(race_id) references race(race_id));
create table Gender(Gender_ID int primary key, Gender varchar(30));
create table Race(Race_ID int primary key, Race varchar(30));
insert into Gender values(1, 'Male');
insert into Gender values(2, 'Female');
insert into Gender values(3, 'Other');
insert into Race values(1, 'White');
insert into Race values(2, 'Black');
insert into Race values(3, 'Asian');
insert into Race values(4, 'Native American');
insert into Race values(5, 'Other');
insert into Student values(1, 'John', 'Smith', 1, 1);
insert into Student values(2, 'Sara', 'Lee', 2, 3);
insert into Student values(3, 'Sam', 'Crawford', 3, 5);
insert into Student values(4, 'Cindy', 'Williams', 2, 2);
```

Below is the ERD relationship diagram in case if you need to take a look:

[ERD Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDokf.png)

**Desired Output using subquery below: **

[Output from Subquery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVHbI.png)

How can I get the same result ***using a subquery*** instead of using inner join?

Comment: So your current query returns the correct result? Why change it? What advantage do you expect?

Comment: Please don't post textual data, such as query results, as images. Why do you want to use subqueries instead of joins? In many cases, perhaps most, joins perform better than subqueries.

Comment: What's wrong with joins?

Comment: The big question is why would you move away from an industry standard? I don’t see any benefits, only downsides in readability and maintenance. Everyone understands a JOIN.  And if they don’t, they should not come even close to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the query without JOINS:

```
SELECT
  (first_name || ' ' || last_name) AS "Student Name",
  (SELECT gender FROM gender WHERE gender_id = student.gender_id) AS gender,
  (SELECT race FROM race WHERE race_id = student.race_id) AS race
FROM
  student;
```

**Output:**
[image]

Note: Its better to use JOINS, as they are faster as compared to SUBQUERIES for indexed data.

Comment: This query is not functionally equivalent to the original query with inner joins: it would be equivalent to the original query with outer joins to `gender` and `race`.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query is the most straight-forward way. Because what you are trying to achieve is to create a joint view of multiple tables fully stitched together using a common key, which is exactly what JOIN is for. Also, subquery is usually used when there are more layers to the question rather than a case of just fully stitching tables together.

If you just don't want to use INNER JOIN, but achieve the result as INNER JOIN, using a CROSS JOIN with WHERE clause does the job as well. But I think it is unnecessary.

```
SELECT
  (s.first_name || ' ' ||s.last_name) AS Student_Name,
  g.Gender AS Gender,
  r.Race AS Race
FROM Student AS s, Gender AS g, Race AS r
WHERE g.Gender_ID = s.gender_id AND r.Race_ID = s.race_id;
```

There are usually 4 types of subquery

1. WITH: this is used when you'd like to pseudo-create a temporary
   table from an existing table and place it at the top of the larger
   query
2. Nested: it is used when you'd like the temporary table to act as a
   filter within the larger query, and it often sits within the WHERE
   clause
3. Inline: it is used in the same way as the WITH. Instead of the
   temporary table sitting on top of the larger query, it's embedded
   within the FROM clause.
4. Scalar: it is used when you want to generate a scalar value to be
   used as a benchmark

None of above is really needed in this case.

On a side note, looking at the ERD, you are indicating that student table has one-to-many relationship with gender table and race table, so one student can have multiple different genders or races? or should it be one race or gender can correspond to multiple students? or are you better off just combining all into one table, race and gender are attributes about a student, then you don't even have to do a join? These are interesting questions to consider.